# Добавление кнопки "Назад" в Action Bar. Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть два фрагмента. Во фрагменте 1 при нажатии кнопки открывается второй фрагмент. Вот код первого фрагмента:

```
public class NotificationsFragment extends Fragment {
    private NotificationsViewModel notificationsViewModel;
    private Button registrationButton, autorisationButton;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        notificationsViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NotificationsViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notifications, container, false);

        registrationButton = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button);
        registrationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RegFragment frg4 = new RegFragment();
                FragmentTransaction trans4 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                trans4.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, frg4);
                trans4.addToBackStack(null);
                trans4.commit();
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Код второго фрагмента, который открывается при нажатии на кнопку в первом:

```
public class RegFragment extends Fragment {
    private RegViewFragment regViewFragment;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        regViewFragment =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(RegViewFragment.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.m_registeration, container, false);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Не могу понять как добавить в Action Bar стрелку, при нажатии на которую, осуществлялся возврат со второго фрагмента на первый. При нажатии на системную кнопку "назад" всё работает.

Внешне это сейчас выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на кнопку Зарегистрироваться открывается следующий фрагмент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нашел на просторах англоязычного интернета следующий способ:
ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
И плюс обработчик для этой кнопки. Но не понятно как его использовать, вроде как по задумке пишу правильно, но приложение вылетает.

Answer (score 2):

Все довольно просто. Добавляете тулбар в xml вашего фрагмента:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

дальше инициализируете его в фрагменте:

```
Toolbar toolbar = root.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

и дальше либо используете этот способ:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the toorbar's NavigationIcon as up/home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            //NavigationIcon
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

либо такой метод:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278878/how-provide-up-navigation-with-toolbars-home-button-on-v7-toolbar) есть много полезной информации.

Comment: У меня уже объявлен Toolbar, точнее ActionBar, был уже при создании проекта. Как я понимаю он объявлен в манифесте строкой android:theme="@style/AppTheme".

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

Это добавляем в метод onCreateView во фрагменте, который открывается при нажатии кнопки:

```
ActionBar actionBar = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Это добавляем не во фрагмент, в котором находится кнопка, вызывающая другой фрагмент, а в MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```